# Teensy 2.0++ SDA SCL pins not accesible using ARDUINO software

Tags: serial, c, softwareserial, mpu6050, teensy

Hi I was looking to interface Teensy++ 2.0 with MPU6050 for a simple IMU project.
I have done this previously using Teensy 3.1 by trying the project of [kriswiner](https://github.com/kriswiner/MPU-6050) however I also wanted to try it out on my Teensy++ 2.0 board.

But when I went to check the pin assignments for Teensy++ 2.0 on the [pjrc](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/pinout.html) website it has been mentioned that the pins PD0 and PD1 can be used as SDA and SCL using [C Language](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/card4a.pdf) but there is no assignment of SDA SCL on Teensy ++ 2.0 using [Arduino Software](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/card4b.pdf)

Does that mean we cannot use these pins using Arduino software at all? Or is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Here is more info https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Wire.html.

Comment: BW What do you mean by ARDUINO software? The core for the Teensy++ 2.0 board is provided by PJRC (and not Arduino LLC). And you can use D0 and D1 for as digital pin, pwm, interrupt or I2C.

Comment: The pin assignments for Teensy ++ 2.0 were mentioned as such on the pjrc page. **using arduino software** [this](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/card4b.pdf) and **using C language** [this](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/card4a.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Guess that ARDUINO software should be interpreted as Arduino API. In any case, I2C is not an issue. You might consider posting PJRC a message about the "misleading documentation".